# Запуск функции из другого класса

Tags: python, python-2.x

Доброй ночи!
Есть файл Myfile1.py, в которой есть функции с глобальными переменными

```
class setup():
 def 00(self):
   global abc
   abc = "hello"
```

и есть файл Myfile2.py, в котором данная переменная должны быть использована

```
class dosmth():
 def 01(self):
  print abc
```

Вопрос: как мне импортировать и запустить функцию в myfile2.py ?

Comment: это не Питон код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, что бы запустить функцию в `Myfile2.py`, импортируйте модуль  `Myfile1.py` и обращайтесь к ней через точку:

```
import Myfile1
Myfile1.имя_функции()
```

Либо импортируйте только имена переменный и функций, которые вам нужны :

```
from Myfile1 import your_func, your_var1, your_var2
```

Тогда обращаться к ним можно без имени модуля.

Для обращения к функциям из другого класса, создайте его экземпляр и вызывайте нужные вам методы:

```
import Myfile1
o = Myfile1.setup()
o.имя_функции()
```

Comment: А как мне использовать глобальные  переменные из другого ?
Глобальная переменная abc определяется в функции (accesstoken при регистрации нового пользователя).  К сожалению, почему-то не цепляет эти переменные

Comment: @Сергей, Попробуйте воспользоваться ключевым словом `global`. К примеру: `global abc`

Comment: @Сергей: в примере в ответе, `setup` является глобальным именем из модуля Myfile1. Если вы можете использовать `setup()`, то абсолютно также можно доступиться и до других глобальных переменных из Myfile1 модуля. В сторону: не используйте глобальные переменные без необходимости (к примеру, почему бы не сделать abc, переменной класса? или вообще обычным атрибутом вашего объекта?). Используйте соглашения имён из pep-8